# Enable Dropdown in a Online Publishing Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a online published google sheet which is basically a Sales team Dashboard I want anyone accessing the published link would be able to change the dropdown in the published link or is there any other way we can do this possibly ?